# Import same Compass Sprite across multiple stylesheets with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, include, compass-sass, css-sprites

Sometimes we have both *regular* and *partial* `.sass` files with `@include` declarations using *the very same sprite images*. This is easily used in **standalone `sass`** because you can `@import icons/*.png` in the main file and `@include icons-sprite` in every of the subsequent *partial* file.

The problem is that with **`sass-rails`** you cannot do the same.

Rails pipeline seems to compile sass files in a way they can't share variables among each other. So the sprite's `@import` declaration becomes available only in the scope of the file where it is declared.

Although, `@import icons/*.png` everywhere you need it causes Rails to generate different overwritten sprite files for the same images, causing the final stylesheets to miss the file name in its `background-image` declarations.

I've been solving this by skipping `sass` partials when they all need the same import declaration, blending them in one sole big stylesheet file, which is not a desirable approach as it mess with code organization, code maintenance, and concern separation.

*Wonder if there's a better approach to this problem, if anyone could share...*

Thank you.